Decomposition of ideal of group ring
Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$ and $G$ a finite group and $g$ an element in $G$ of order $n$. Suppose that we know the decomposition of $kG$ into irreducible characters $\bigoplus_i (\dim V_i) \chi_i$. Is there any text that showcases in general how to find how many times each $\chi_i$ appears on the decomposition of an ideal $I \subseteq kG$? More specifically for the ideal $(1+g+\cdots + g^{n-1})kG$?

Welcome to math SE. Where does this problem comes from? Have you tried anything?

Thank you!, it shows up somewhere in my research. I suppose if $G$ is a cyclic group generated by $g$ then the regular representation contains only one-dimensional characters and since $1+g+\cdots +g^{n-1}$ annihilates $g$ then the ideal I am asking for contains only the principal character. This is also easy to generalize to direct products of cyclic groups. I would like to know if there is any sort of treatment in a text/book that I am missing or any other written examples
